# I need help with using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to filter the objects that I have by their topic.

I have many topics: Arts, Economics, Business, Politics. Each topic is a property within the object that I try to classify from a list of those objects.

Here is part of my objects:

```
public class AllQuestionsPresented
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string ThreadName { get; set; }
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public string Subtopic { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
    public int Replies { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    // snip
```

I created many of those objects feed their properties with different values and  put them into a List:

```
List<AllQuestionsPresented> forumData;
```

Now I want to group them all into linq by their topics..

```
var groupedByPages =
    from n in forumData
    group n by forumData
    select .....
```

Basically i dont know how to continue cause i am not used to deal with linq.. what i want to get is some dictionary..

```
Dictionary<string,AllQuestionsPresented> dictionary..
```

If i dont use linq, and add to a dictionary every topic, it will put several "AllQuestionsPresented" objects with the same topic..which will throw an exception..so i have to use group by..but dont know how to achieve that manipulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call `ToDictionary`. The parameters are a function to select the keys and another to select the values:

```
var groupedByPages =
    from n in forumData
    group n by n.Topic;

IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<AllQuestionsPresented>> dictionary = 
    groupedByPages.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.AsEnumerable());
```

But if all you need from the `IDictionary` interface is the indexing operation, it's easier to just use a `ILookup`:

```
ILookup<string, AllQuestionsPresented> groupedByPages = forumData.ToLookup(x => x.Topic);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ToLookup`, which will give you a key/list of values collection.  Your key will be the `Topic`, and you will get a list of `AllQuestionsPresented` for each key.

```
var lookup = forumData.ToLookup(f => f.Topic);
```

[Reference on ToLookup](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tolookup)

Comment: How do i transfer this all to a dictionary? ToDictionary..takes arguments..but what do i give it as an argument

Comment: A dictionary is probably not the appropriate collection to use. A dictionary has a key and a **single** value, whereas an `ILookup` has a key with a **list** of values.  In your scenario, you have a **list** of threads, keyed off their topic.

Comment: the the value of a dictionary can of course be a `List<AllQuestionsPresented>`

Answer (score 1):

```
var groupedByTopics = 
from n in forumData
group n by forumData.Topic into g
select new { Topic = forumData.Topic, Questions = g }
```

You may also want to keep this around for reference :-)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746

Comment: i do have this as a reference :X

Answer (score 1):

The grouped results are returned as an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, T>>`, which in your case will be `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, AllQuestionsPresented>>`.

The code below shows how you can access the data in the grouping.

```
  var groupedByTopic = from question in forumData 
                       group question by question.Topic;

  foreach (var group in groupedByTopic)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
    foreach (var question in group)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("\t" + question.Name);
    }
  }
```

To create a dictionary from the above you can do the following

```
var groupingDictionary = groupedByTopic.ToDictionary(q=>q.Key, q=>q.ToList());
```

Which will give you a `Dictionary<string, List<AllQuestionsPresented>>`

If you went the LookUp route, which is nicely demonstrated by @wsanville
, then you can get the dictionary the same way

```
  var lookup = forumData.ToLookup(q => q.Topic);
  var groupingDictionary = lookup.ToDictionary(q => q.Key, q => q.ToList());
```

Comment: The toList in the end is not correct cause i get a mistake..:(

Comment: @Matrix001, what error do you get? I just tested the code and it works, are you getting a compile error or a runtime error?

Answer (score 0):

```
var groupedByPages =
    from n in forumData
    group n by forumData.Topic
    select n;
```